# Translate Java to Clojure - append to list and return list

Tags: java, clojure, functional-programming

I want to translate the following java to idiomatic clojure:

```
List<SimpleRecord> recs = new ArrayList<SimpleRecord>();
ParquetReader<SimpleRecord> reader = null;
    try {
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Main.out, true);
      reader = new ParquetReader<SimpleRecord>(new Path(input), new SimpleReadSupport());
      for (SimpleRecord value = reader.read(); value != null; value = reader.read()) {
        //value.prettyPrint(writer);
        //writer.println();
        recs.add(value);
      }
      return value;
    } finally {
      if (reader != null) {
        try {
          reader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
      }
    }
```

But I'm having trouble pushing an element to the list at each step.
This is what I have right now:

```
(let [rows   (vector)
      reader (new parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader (new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path "file.pq") 
                                               (new SimpleReadSupport))]
  ;reader  
  (try   
    (for [value (.read reader) :while (not (nil? value))]
      (conj value rows)) ;y u no recur?
    rows
    (finally (.close reader)))
  )
```

But I don't know whats the idiomatic way of doing this within a `for`. I'm guessing I have to use `reduce` no? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` in Clojure is not a for loop, it is a sequence comprehension.

The default Clojure datastructures, being immutible, should be built iteratively rather than mutated inside an iteration.

```
(with-open [reader (parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader. 
                     (org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path. "file.pq") 
                     (SimpleReadSupport.))]
  (doall
   (take-while (complement nil?)
               (repeatedly (fn []
                             (try (.read reader)
                                  (catch Exception e))))))
```

Comment: Good use of line-seq. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I blatantly copy/pasted your elimination of new / with-open :)

Comment: Ah, I just glanced at the javadoc, ParquetReader does not extend java.io.reader.  Maybe switch this to use iterate/take-while just for an alternative (assuming his base-case was right in the first place).

Comment: updated, thanks (if only the formatter understood the `#()` notation)

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing anything about parquet or what you're trying to do, here's my best guess and some observations:

```
(with-open [reader (parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader. 
                     (org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path. "file.pq") 
                     (SimpleReadSupport.))]
  (doall (for [value (repeatedly #(.read reader))
               :while value] 
           value))
```

`nil` and `false` are falsy, everything else is truthy, if `value` is never false then just use `value` instead of `(not (nil? value))`.  (Extra Gotcha: `(Boolean. false)` is truthy, see https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L2607 :)

Does it need to be a vector, why?  This code here returns a seq, which is realized ahead of time by doall (to be scoped within the with-open, equivalent to your try-finally.)

Clojure's data is immutable, you don't append to a list, you tell it to create a new one from an old one and let Clojure handle the details :-).  There's nothing you can do in your code sample to change the value of `rows` once it's set, there's no 'variables'.  There *are* mutable reference types, but it would be bad form to use them here.  Technically, you *could* implement this with loop/recur, but there's no reason for that here (maybe performance), and there are real benefits to using the lazy-sequence approach in general.

`reduce` wouldn't work because it eliminates the ability to exit early, also the input here is a java object and `reduce` expects a seq-able thing, so you'd still have to find some way to generate a lazy sequence and you're back to square one.

`for` is not a loop, it's a list-comprehension.  It generates a lazy sequence of values.

I don't consider `new` idiomatic, I'm not sure why :-).  It's a better choice for code generation with macros, though.

Spend the time to understand these concepts, they're wonderful in practice!

Comment: `reduce` can exit early via `reduced`.

Comment: shouldn't there be a repeatedly in the code since (.read reader) returns only one single value?

Comment: I'm hitting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: parquet.tools.read.SimpleRecord`; besides all my elements in the seq are the same! But thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Just replace (.read reader) with (repeatedly #(.read reader))

Comment: @SpiderPig Programming is hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

gtrak's approach is of course the best one, but I still wanted to show you how to write an explicit loop in clojure.

```
(with-open [reader (parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader. 
                     (org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path. "file.pq") 
                     (SimpleReadSupport.))]
  (loop [rows []]
    (let [value (.read reader)]
      (if value
          (recur (conj rows value))
          rows))))
```